# Is there a way to retrieve twitter handle/id and facebook id from a valid email address?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter

Is there a way to retrieve twitter handle/id and facebook id from a valid email address?

Given a list of email addresses, can we find the twitter account ids and facebook ids associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get the IDs with only the email address. You should not connect any account without letting the user authorize it anyway. People may not want their accounts to be auto-connected with their email.